# Using the verb petition

Tags: word-usage

Please tell which of the following correct.
If none is correct, please suggest an alternative. 
Thanks for help.

1. I am petitioning for my wife an immigrant visa.
2. I am petitioning for my wife's immigration visa.
3. I am filing a petition for my wife an immigrant visa.
4. I am filing a petition for my wife's immigrant visa.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sentences #2 and #4 sound natural.

Th phrase you are using is

> petitioning for *something(object)*
>
> petitioning for my wife. *(OK, but ambiguous, petitioning your wife for what?)*
>   petitioning for an immigrant visa. *(OK)*
>   petitioning for my wife an immigrant visa. *(awkward, but understandable)*

You might use

> petitioning for an immigrant visa ***for*** my wife.
>   petitioning for my wife ***to get*** an immigrant visa.